# Java script Time addition

Tags: javascript, time

What would be the best way to do time addition, i was playing with date objects, and even trying to setup my math calculation for adding time. But the results are not always correct;

example like

```
var time1 = '00:30'; //string
var time2 = '17:30'; //string
var time_val = (( parseInt(time1) * 0.6 ) + parseInt(time2)) / 60;
```

Comment: Do it with Date instances.

Comment: checkout http://momentjs.com/ if you are playing date objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solid solution:

```
var newDateObj = new Date(time_to_change.getTime() + time*60000);
```

where `time_to_change` is the date object to add time to and `time` variable is the variable of minutes to increase the time